# Is there any way to change the default output shape of a fully connected layer in a convolutional neural network?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm reading a [paper](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~deigen/dnl/dnl_iccv15.pdf) about depth prediction using a Multi-Scale CNN.

Based on paper, they used AlexNet or VGGNet in the first scale.

I'm also interested in using VGGNet for that. There are some dark points in my mind about the topic. As an example, as you can see in the following table, the output of the second FC layer (1.6 & 1.7 are FC layers) has an strange shape of 19*14:

[image]

As I understood, FC layers are not spatially located, so their output shape should be one-dimensional:

**1 * (# of outputs)** for each sample in the mini-batch, (here my batch size is 16):

[image]

So this is my question:

Is there any way to change the parameters of an FC layer to have such a dimension (19*14) at the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such parameters in FC layer, but you can use a Reshape layer to reshape the output to the size you want.

The output of the FC layer would be `64x266`. You can reshape it into `64x19x14`.

Documentation for Reshape layer: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html

Comment: Although it will blow up number of the parameters in the network, it seems that there is no other way to implement what the authors did. So, I need to define the dimension of 1.7 layer as (BS * 17024) and then reshape it into (BS*64*19*14). Thanks.

Comment: You should at least link to the documentation of rehsape layer.